# Magnetic locks with paramagnetic materials

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetics, physics

Well I was wondering why magnetic locks are made of an electromagnet and a ferromagnetic material and not an electromagnet and a paramagnetic material.

The magnetic attraction between the electromagnet and material attached at the edge of the door will create a 2nd axis of rotation.

Ferromagnetic materials remain magnetized even after the electromagnet no longer exists.The magnetic field of the ferromagnet will magnetize the conductor.This wont destroy the 2nd axis of rotation meaning the door cannot be opened.

Paramagnetic materials don't remain magnetized after the electromagnet no longer exists.This will destroy the 2nd axis of rotation meaning the door can be opened rotating on the 1st axis of rotation.

Comment: "This wont destroy the 2nd axis of rotation meaning the door cannot be opened."  I open doors with a de-activated magnetic lock every day...Also, in something like a lock, strength of the attraction matters so not retaining any magnetization is secondary to being strongly attracted. Iron is also cheap.

Comment: `Well I was wondering why magnetic locks are made of an electromagnet and a ferromagnetic material and not an electromagnet and a paramagnetic material.` Because ferromangetic materials are more magnetic. Why would you want a magnet lock that's weak like a paramagnetic material?

Comment: This is a response to both of you.If the magnetic field induced by current is strong enough then it shouldnt matter because the magnetic strength will be big even if the material at the edge of the door is paramagnetic.

Comment: @MrsChemistry In real life, things like energy consumption, cost of the paramagnetic material, and cost of the electromagnet matter. Not to mention safety. Do you really want your maglock door to be so powerful it can rip your steel keys out of your hand with a force stronger than it holds the door shut? Do you want your maglock door to be consuming 1000+ watts (and likely much much more) 24 hours a day? That also throws a wrench into your battery backup systems. You might as well just go with a keyed lock if that were the case.

Comment: It's a bit like saying "we should build swords out of bronze because it doesn't rust like steel. You can just use more bronze to make the sword just as strong." It heavily prioritizes a very minor consideration over many more important ones.

Comment: @DKNguyen the pressure to fracture bronze will be always less than the pressure to fracture steel

Comment: @MrsChemistry Exactly. And paramagnetic materials always have a weaker attraction than ferromagnetic ones. Why do you buy sword argument but not the magnet argument? I only care how much force it takes to bend my sword and you only care about force to hold the door. I don't care about pressure just like how you don't care how magnetically attractive the material is. I can always just use more bronze to make as word that is harder to bend than a steel sword, just like you can always use more electromagnet to make up for the weaker paramagnetic attraction.

Comment: To be more explicit, saying you can use an enormous electromagnet to make up for the weaker paramagnetic attraction would be like me saying that my bronze sword which is 4" thick takes more force to bend than a sword which is only 1/2 inch thick, and therefore practical, if not even better. Do see how ridiculous and impractical they both sound?

Comment: @DKNguyen lets say I agree for the moment.But will the magnetic force between the magnetized material and the magnetized conductor be less than the magnetic force between the electromagnet and the magnetized material?

Comment: @MrsChemistry What are you referring to when you say "magnetized material" and "magnetized conductor"? I'm also going to ask you to say specifically what you mean by electromagnet as well in case you are using the term unconventionally.

Comment: Magnetized material is that thing at the edge of the door when it is magnetized.Electromagnet is the conductor with current.Magnetized conductor is the conductor magnetized due to the magnetic field of the ferromagnetic material (at the edge of the door).But wait a minute if the conductor is made of a paramagnetic material then it should work out.

Comment: @MrsChemistry It's still unclear to me what you are talking about. It's not even clear to me if all three components are on the same door setup at the same time, or if you are talking about two different door setups. It's also not clear to me what you mean by "magnetized conductor is the conductor magnetized due to the magnetic field of the ferromagnetic material". You pass a current through a conductor to produce a magnetic field (an electromagnet). This magnetic field can be concentrated by using a core material. The magnetic field generated can magnetize other ferromagnetic materials.

Comment: Ok never mind I figured a way out.